# unable to select another option after selection with react select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Updated code: Im trying to first display carsList and only when selectedMake is selected, I would update the state with the result from filter and show another array. I tried storing carsList in updatedCarsList so it has all the cars on page load but Im missing something here.

CarOffers.jsx

```
const CarOffers = () => {
    const [carsList, setCarsList] = useState([]);
    const [updatedCarsList, setUpdatedCarsList] = useState([]);
    const [selectedMake, setSelectedMake] = useState(undefined);

    const getCars = () => {
      axios.get(url)
      .then((response) => {
         return setCarsList(response.data)
      })
   }
   const handleMakeChange = (select) => {
    setSelectedMake(select.value) 
   }

   const applyFilters = () => {
    let updatedCarsList = carsList

   if(selectedMake) {
    updatedCarsList = carsList.filter(car => car.make === selectedMake)
       setUpdatedCarsList(updatedCarsList);
   } else  { 
    setUpdatedCarsList(carsList)
   }
  
  }
  
    useEffect(() => {
      getCars()
      applyFilters()
  }, [ selectedMake ]);

  return (
    <div className="mka__wrapper-car-offers">
      <div className="mka__container">
        <div className="mka__content-car-offers">
          <div className="mka__content-grid-offers">
          <div className="item1">
          < CarSlider/>
          <div className="mka-responsive-item">
          < DisplayCars/>
          < SortingCars/>
          < CarAlignment/>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div className="item2">
            <div className="mka__side-bar-divider">
          < Search 
          carsList={carsList}/>
          </div>
          <div>
          < FilterSideBar
          carsList={carsList}
          handleMakeChange={handleMakeChange} />
          </div>
          </div>
          <div className="item3">
          <Cars updatedCarsList={updatedCarsList}/>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


export default CarOffers;
```

Cars.jsx

```
const Cars = ({ updatedCarsList }) => {
    return (
        <div className='mka__cars-grid'>
        {updatedCarsList.map(car =>
            <CarsItem key={car.id} car={car}/>)}
        </div>
    )
  }



export default Cars
```

CarItem.jsx

```
const CarsItem = ({car: {year,month,transmission,mileage,price,title,link}}) => {
   
    return (
      <Fragment>
      <div className="cars-item_wrapper">
        <div className="cars-item_image">
          <img src={link} alt="car" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <a
            className="cars-item_car-title"
            href="/"
          >
           {title}
          </a>
        </div>
        <div className=" cars-item_separator"></div>
          <p className="cars-item_car-text">{price}</p>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
    )
  }

export default CarsItem
```

Comment: please provide stackblitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your applyFilters above getCars

Does Select need to be in <>

distinctBy... urgh.. use Set `const unique = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.value))]`

applyFilters... axios is async, but your setting a value so state doesn't update so no re-render? Maybe.

selectedMake - don't use null as a default, use undefined.

Hope that helps, feels like a state management issue.

... think its this ....

You are using carsList as your list of cars, however you are setting the value of carsList with setCarsList(updatedCarsList)... updatedCarsList is a filtered list of cars... only `car => car.make ===  selectedMake` so once you've selected a make your carList is only cars with the selected make.

Solution is to

- Either separate the list from the filtered list
- or preferably keep list, but pass the filtered state to the component that needs it... but not update state of the original list by calling `setCarsList(updatedCarsList);`

```
if (selectedMake){
   updatedCarsList = updatedCarsList.filter(
      car => car.make ===  selectedMake
   )
}; 
setCarsList(updatedCarsList);
```

Comment: Select is in < /> as it is a component. Applied suggested changes but it still doesnt show other options in dropdown. It rerenders perfectly and shows the cars with the make I selected in a dropdown but all other options that aren't selected disappear.

Comment: <> is there for you to group multiple elements, but if you are returning only one there should be no need for it.

Comment: So what is the dropdown - FilterSideBar presumably? Feel like its in your handleChange - i'd get logging in there and have a look about.

Comment: Its a react-select node package. I populated the dropdown with car.make as a value of the options. And it works well but when I select BMW and want to reselect a different make, only BMW make is there for reselect.

Comment: update above - your setting cars as the selected.